# icCube Reporting - Labels using Events: Formatting and Syntax

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

What is the correct syntax for using the event variable within the label boxes (e.g Header Title).

Having a defined event (e.g. Test), what are the possible use?
What is the meaning of the following expression?

@{Test:'Alternate Text'!} @{Test}

Are there other available functions?

Answer (score 2):

Events in icCube are objects (base class is viz.event.Event) that implement mainly two methods :

- caption() - return the caption/name of the event, e.g. Italy for a country MDX member
- asMdx()   - return the mdx unique name (caption if there is none), e.g. [Country].[Italy]

So when you define an event listener **@{eventName}** it's going to be changed by it's caption() value, unless you are in an MDX expression where it's changed by the asMdx() value.

You can *decorate* your event in three ways

```
@{eventName!emptyValue}         -> if the event is empty, returns  the string 'emptyValue' (without single quotes)
@{eventName:eventFunction}      -> calls eventObject.eventFunction , e.g. @{event:asMdx}
@{eventName:'valueIfNotEmpty'}  -> if the event exists, return the string 'valueIfNotEmpty' (without single quotes)
```

More information on the [doc](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/reporting/doc/ic3Events.php).

As it's javascript you're free to add you own methods to the object of the class (e.g.  using *On Send Event* hook in a widget - the JS icon)

The interface that all events implement is :

```
   export interface IEvent {
        /**
         * Return true if the event is empty.
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        isEmptyEvent():boolean;

        /**
         * Returns the caption of the event.
         * @returns {string}
         */
        caption():string;

        /**
         * Returns the value of the event.
         * @returns {string}
         */
        value():any;

        /**
         * Returns the event value as MDX expression.
         * @returns {string}
         */
        asMdx():string;

        /**
         * Return the event value key
         * @return {string}
         */
        asKey():string;

        /**
         * Return the string representation of member key with quotes. If multiple keys present it returns: 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
         * @return {string}
         */
        asQuotedKey():string;

        /**
         * Return the string representation of member captions with quotes. If multiple keys present it returns: 'name1, 'name2', 'name3'
         * @return {string}
         */
        asQuotedCaption():string;

        /**
         * Return the array of event keys
         * @return {Array}
         */
        asKeyArray():string[];

        /**
         * Returns the event value es MDX set expression.
         * @returns {string}
         */
        asSet():string;

        /**
         * Returns the event value as filter initial selection.
         * @returns {any}
         */
        asFilterInitialSelection():any;

        /**
         * Return true if the event is selection event. Used for type check.
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        isSelectionEvent():boolean;

        /**
         * Returns the event value as an array.
         * @returns {any[]}
         */
        getSelectedItems():any[];

        /**
         * Returns a serialized event object.
         * @returns {EventGuts}
         */
        asReportParam():EventGuts;
    }
```